# A less than 6 character edit from a new user?

Tags: support, editing

I am puzzling over [this edit](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/9393/revisions) which appears to be less than 6 characters. In a recent edit that I suggested I had to change a punctuation mark to make it pass muster. Of course I could have also used [some tricks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters) to circumvent the character change limit. I am aware of that. But [that edit](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/9393/revisions) at issue doesn't appear to include extra characters. So how did it happen?

Comment: I asked about a similar case a week ago on Meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359885/295232

Comment: I think when you get 2000 rep you can unilaterally make edits of any size. Not far to go for you now :-)

Comment: @user3856370 Haha, that's true. I can do unilateral edits on two sites now, and am looking forward to Japanese SE becoming the third one. Still like to feed my curiosity though. :)